# How to get the ruid, euid, suid and rgid, egid, sgid of a process?

Tags: linux, process

How to get the `ruid` (real user ID), `euid` (effective user ID), `suid` (saved user ID) and `rgid` (real group ID), `egid` (effective group ID), `sgid` (saved group ID) of a process, can it be done using `ps`?

Answer (score 6):

With Debian's `procps-ng`:

```
$ ps -o pid,euid,ruid,suid,egid,rgid,sgid,cmd
  PID  EUID  RUID  SUID  EGID  RGID  SGID CMD
28793  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000 -/bin/bash
...
```

Under `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` [in the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html):

> ```
> euid        EUID      effective user ID (alias uid).
> euser       EUSER     effective user name.  This will be the textual
>                       user ID, if it can be obtained and the field
>                       width permits, or a decimal representation
>                       otherwise.
> ```

etc.

[FreeBSD `ps`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ps(1)) has `svuid` and `svgid` instead of `suid` and `sgid` and the one that comes with macOS only knows `uid` and `gid` for the effective UID and GID (not `euid` or `egid`).

On Linux, there's also the filesystem access UID and GID though it's probably not used much (see [`setfsuid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setfsuid.2.html)). The specifiers for those are `fuid`/`fsuid` and `fgid`/`fsgid`.

`/proc/$pid/status` also contains them, see [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: `ps` is giving me: "ERROR: Unsupported option (BSD syntax)".

Comment: @ilkkachu You've made a typo, "ps -opid..." should be "ps -o pid...".

Comment: @user7681202, works both ways on `procps-ng` and on the macOS BSD `ps`. Does it make a difference in some implementation?

Comment: @ilkkachu Sorry, it works like you did too ("ps -opid..."). I thought it didn't work because I put a space after the commas.